# Compilation error, undefined function in Elixir

Tags: compilation, elixir

I am making a poker hand analyzer in Elixir. The program takes an input of 52 ints and distributes 5 odd (indexed) cards to player1 and 5 even (indexed) cards to player2, before deciding whose hand is better. I made a function for each player (below). When I try and compile, compiler throws an error: (CompileError) poker.ex:49: undefined function player1/1. I have tried a lot of things, but they all seem to fail, please help!

```
defmodule Poker do

  decks = %{ 1 => "2C", 2 => "3C", 3 => "4C", 4 => "5C", 5 => "6C", 6 => "7C", 7 => "8C",
    8=> "9C", 9=> "10C", 10 => "11C", 11 => "12C", 12 => "13C", 13 => "1C", 14 => "2D",
    15 => "3D", 16=> "4D", 17 => "5D", 18=> "6D", 19=> "7D", 20=> "8D", 21=> "9D",
    22=> "10D", 23=> "11D", 24=> "12D", 25=> "13D", 26=> "1D", 27=> "2H", 28=> "3H",
    29=> "4H", 30=> "5H", 31=> "6H", 32=> "7H", 33=> "8H", 34=> "9H", 35=> "10H",
    36=> "11H", 37=> "12H", 38=> "13H", 39=> "1H", 40=> "2S", 41=> "3S", 42=> "4S",
    43=> "5S", 44=> "6S", 45=> "7S", 46=> "8S", 47=> "9S", 48=> "10S", 49=> "11S",
    50=> "12S", 51=> "13S", 52=> "1S"}
  defp player1(cards), do: Enum.take(Enum.drop_every(cards, 2), 5)

  defp player2(cards) do
    Enum.take(
      cards -- (Enum.drop_every(cards, 2)) ,5)
  end
  mapHand = for n <- player1(cards), do: Map.get(decks, n)
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more details? Are these functions inside a module? And if so, is the `mapHand = for n...` match also happening within the same module?

Comment: yes, its all happening within the same module. 
defmodule Poker do

Comment: But `mapHand` is not inside any function or anything like that? And where is `decks` coming from?

Comment: I just put all of the code in to make more sense of it.

Comment: If I put mapHand within player1 function, the compiler complains undefined function decks

Comment: One last question. At the end, when you put `for n <- player1(cards)`, what is `cards` referring to?

Comment: I wanted to reference the output of function player1(cards)[where cards in player1, is the input of 52 ints (and output of player1 is 5 cards, which I want to provide as input to mapHand)]. Essentially mapHand is supposed to enumerate all the ints of the output generated by player1(cards) and generate a new list, with values taken from the map called decks.

Comment: Check my answer below. I wouldn't suggest using matches `x = 1` anywhere but in scripts or within functions, of course. If you're using modules, use functions or module attributes `@x 1` (although that's also not a good idea to use them as variables). Then, it depends a lot on your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some problems with your code. And the solution mostly depends on what you want to do. It would help you a great deal to take a look at https://elixir-lang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical/scoping.html to get a better understanding of the scoping rules in Elixir.

The most straightforward solution I would suggest in your case, would be to replace all of the matches e.g.`mapHand = for n <- ...` for functions. Like so:

```rb
defmodule Poker do                                                                              
  defp decks do
    %{ 1 => "2C", 2 => "3C", 3 => "4C", 4 => "5C", 5 => "6C", 6 => "7C", 7 => "8C",
      8=> "9C", 9=> "10C", 10 => "11C", 11 => "12C", 12 => "13C", 13 => "1C", 14 => "2D",         
      15 => "3D", 16=> "4D", 17 => "5D", 18=> "6D", 19=> "7D", 20=> "8D", 21=> "9D",              
      22=> "10D", 23=> "11D", 24=> "12D", 25=> "13D", 26=> "1D", 27=> "2H", 28=> "3H",            
      29=> "4H", 30=> "5H", 31=> "6H", 32=> "7H", 33=> "8H", 34=> "9H", 35=> "10H",               
      36=> "11H", 37=> "12H", 38=> "13H", 39=> "1H", 40=> "2S", 41=> "3S", 42=> "4S",             
      43=> "5S", 44=> "6S", 45=> "7S", 46=> "8S", 47=> "9S", 48=> "10S", 49=> "11S",              
      50=> "12S", 51=> "13S", 52=> "1S"}                                                          
  end

  defp player1(cards), do: Enum.take(Enum.drop_every(cards, 2), 5)                              

  defp player2(cards) do
    Enum.take(cards -- (Enum.drop_every(cards, 2)), 5)
  end

  def map_hand(cards) do
    for n <- player1(cards), do: Map.get(decks(), n )
  end
end
```

That way you could then (outside of the module) do something like:

```rb
player_1_cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Poker.map_hand(player_1_cards)
```

And get something like:

```rb
["3C", "5C"]
```

Comment: The overall goal is to call a function called deal with 52 ints. Something like, Poker.deal([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10......52]) and display the winning hand. Player1 would be [2,4,6,8,10] and player2 [1,3,5,7,9]. My question is, how does one function lead to another function. Can one function just be calling another function, until the winning hand is displayed? Is there a way to store player1 cards in a variable that I can call again and again?

Comment: Sure you can.  This module could be your starting point. You could then have another module `Game` or something like that, which calls the functions of `Poker`. Or you could simply add the function `deal` within this module, which defines the initial cards for players, and then does whatever it needs using map_hand, decks, and whatnot. You need to think of what you need your code to do and define a sort of "flow". Functions defined with `defp` can only be used in the same module. The ones defined with `def` can be called from other modules

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: @maulajutt if the answer helped, you are supposed to mark it as correct with a green checkmark right below the score.

Comment: Done! Thanks for letting me know Aleksei.